# What is causing my SVG file to be chunked by Webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, svg, webpack

I'm using VueJS and within my scoped SCSS I have a background image pointing to an SVG file and that works fine... but when I try to use a loader like file-loader/url-loader/svg-url-loader to configure the ouput, it is being chunked and unable to be read. I have no idea what could be causing the conflict.

```
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {

  mode: 'development',

  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/assets/',
  },

  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: false,
    port: 7000,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/css/[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),

    new VueLoaderPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
      filename: path.join(__dirname, './dist/index.html'),
      minify: false,
    }),

  ],

  devtool: 'source-map',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.vue'],
  },

};
```

the chunked output is something like:
module.exports = "data:image/svg+xml,blahblahblah"

Comment: The problem is rather than actually exporting the SVG file that can be read as an SVG file i.e: starts with <svg>, the svg is processed as a webpack module and its contents start with module.exports = "data:image/svg+xml,blahblahblah"

Comment: Yes, but as I said, it's not processed as an SVG file and does not have the correct SVG markup, it literally has webpack module code inside the file trying to export itself which results in parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself by upgrading all my NPM packages and using Webpack's [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead of any of the previous loaders and it works perfect.